# Does string::replace invallidate iterators and references?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Hello I've searched for iterator and reference invalidation of class string but I didn't find a result.

I have this code:

```
int main(){
    std::string s = "const char* manipulation in C++";
    auto beg = s.cbegin();
    auto& r = *s.begin();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*beg: " << *beg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;

    s.replace(beg, beg + 11, "string");
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*beg: " << *beg << std::endl;        
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;

}
```

The output:

```
const char* manipulation in C++
*beg: c
r: c
string manipulation in C++
*beg: s
r: s
```

It looks good but I don't know whether it is undefined behavior or not. Thank you!

Comment: As a broad rule, you can say that iterators are invalidated only if `string::capacity()` is different after the operation.

Comment: [Any iterators, pointers and references related to this object may be invalidated.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: Simply refer to the documentation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/):

> Any iterators, pointers and references related to this object may be
>   invalidated.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. So each reallocation invalidates all iterators and references and pointers? This is because of the memory locations being changed?

Comment: Yes. When memory for contentious containers like `string` and `vector` has to  be reallocated, all iterators and pointers are invalidated.

Answer (score 3):

According to [[string.require]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.require#4), it seems so:

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_­string` sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that `basic_­string` object:
>
> — **Calling non-const member functions**, except `operator[]`, `at`, `data`, `front`, `back`, `begin`, `rbegin`, `end`, and `rend`.

I believe that if you make the string smaller by `replace`, an implementation may decide to reduce the capacity, which would reallocate.

**UPDATE**

According to the C++11 Standard, the used overload of `replace` specifies only `out_of_range` exception. That would imply (?), that `replace` itself cannot reallocate and therefore it cannot change its capacity. Though, I am not sure if library functions may or may not throw exceptions that are not particularly specified.

In the referenced Draft, [the relevant overload mentions also exceptions thrown by allocator's `allocate` member function](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.replace-8.3), which implies the possibility of reallocation. I don't see any clause that would restrict this exception specification only to cases where the replacement causes enlargement of the original string.

Comment: Ok Thanks I got it now. I've created an empty string then tested for `capacity` which was `15` then I assign iterators and references then I called `replace ` passing in a const-character-string longer than capacity then I've tried to print references and iterators values. The result I got Assertion Dialog which means  they've been invalidated. Thanks.

Comment: But I've tested it on `C++14` and `replace` had caused re-allocation thus iterator, reference, pointer invalidation?!

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa I don't have the C++14 Standard and the referenced Draft is much more complicated because your overload actually has the effect of the overload that involves `std::string_view`. In my tests, the capacity was not changed with GCC and Clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EzoybHNlpEdritNV.